# Ways to upload external data files to Apache Solr

Tags: json, docker, curl, solr

## Context

I am running [official Docker Hub Apache Solr 7.4 image](https://github.com/docker-solr/docker-solr) inside GCP Kubernetes Engine.

## Issue

I need to upload JSON documents to the index. In the past I've only had experience uploading documents stored on the same machine that hosts Solr instance using `bin/post` command or the Admin UI.

Now I need to upload quite a few JSON documents from my machine to the Solr instance in the Docker container (86 documents ~30MB each to be exact). Adding so much extra data to the image doesn't make sense. And [JSON Formatted Index Updates](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_4/uploading-data-with-index-handlers.html#json-formatted-index-updates) docs page only provides two options:

- Uploading JSON docs located on the same machine as Solr instance or
- Specifying JSON document directly in the curl command

I tired adding the documents using commands that I would expect to work (note that I use `localhost` here since I test the Docker image locally first, but the idea is the same):

```
curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/my_core/update?commit=true' --data-binary @/my/local/data/part1.json -H 'Content-type:application/json'
```

But the above returns `500` status code. I tried a few other variations of this and none worked.

What is the best way to upload external data files to Apache Solr?

It would also help if you provide some alternative solution appropriate for my context.

## Additional info

## Small sample JSON file

It's only 2 docs but I get the same result when trying to upload them in a file.

```
[{"iframe":"<iframe src=\"https:\/\/www.example.com\/embed\/ph5b8e18ce6b447\" frameborder=\"0\" height=\"481\" width=\"608\" scrolling=\"no\"><\/iframe>","main_thumbnail_url":"https:\/\/ci.excdn.com\/file\/201809\/04\/181459731\/original\/(m=eaf8Ggaaaa)(mh=sYnlTgQZyb7M8XKU)8.jpg","title":"Example 1","tags":["t1","t2","t3","t4","t5"],"categories":["a","b","c","d","e","f"],"author_name":null,"duration":501,"views":0,"likes":0,"dislikes":0,"likes_ratio":0.0,"id":4250000},{"iframe":"<iframe src=\"https:\/\/www.example.com\/embed\/ph5b8e18c2943af\" frameborder=\"0\" height=\"481\" width=\"608\" scrolling=\"no\"><\/iframe>","main_thumbnail_url":"https:\/\/ci.excdn.com\/files\/201809\/04\/181459741\/original\/(m=eaf8Ggaaaa)(mh=uumefyKUUQmKHNx0)5.jpg","title":"Example 2","tags":["t1","t2"],"categories":["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i"],"author":null,"duration":53,"views":0,"likes":0,"dislikes":0,"likes_ratio":0.0,"id":4250001}]
```

### Stacktrace

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":500,
    "QTime":6},
  "error":{
    "trace":"java.lang.NullPointerException\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory$AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessor.mapValueClassesToFieldType(AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory.java:509)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory$AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessor.processAdd(AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory.java:396)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:55)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:118)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:55)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:118)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:55)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:118)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:55)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:118)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:55)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldNameMutatingUpdateProcessorFactory$1.processAdd(FieldNameMutatingUpdateProcessorFactory.java:75)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:55)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:118)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:55)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.AbstractDefaultValueUpdateProcessorFactory$DefaultValueUpdateProcessor.processAdd(AbstractDefaultValueUpdateProcessorFactory.java:92)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JsonLoader$SingleThreadedJsonLoader.handleAdds(JsonLoader.java:501)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JsonLoader$SingleThreadedJsonLoader.processUpdate(JsonLoader.java:145)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JsonLoader$SingleThreadedJsonLoader.load(JsonLoader.java:121)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JsonLoader.load(JsonLoader.java:84)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.UpdateRequestHandler$1.load(UpdateRequestHandler.java:97)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:68)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:199)\n\tat org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2539)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:709)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:515)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:377)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:323)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1634)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:219)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:531)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:352)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:281)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:760)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:678)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)\n",
    "code":500}}
```

## Edit:

It's something about the format of my JSON files... I can upload [Solr example JSON file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/lucene-solr/master/solr/example/exampledocs/books.json) without any problems.

I am pretty sure my file is a properly formatted JSON since I got it by [saving a Pandas DataFrame as JSON](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html). Python standard `json` module can load the file without any problems as well. So it has to do something with how Solr/Java reads my file.

Comment: Which error/stacktrace do you get? The default file upload size for Jetty (which Solr uses internally) is 200k, so you might be hitting a upload file size limit (I'm guessing it has been tuned for Solr's bundled version, but you might need to increase the value further)

Comment: @MatsLindh when using `curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/my_core/update?commit=true' --data-binary @/my/local/data/part1.json -H 'Content-type:application/json'` I get 500 status code and see two entries in stacktrace `RequestHandlerBase java.lang.NullPointerException` and `HttpSolrCall null:java.lang.NullPointerException`. I tried it with 5KB file and get the same result

Comment: Getting a 500 error is different from getting a 400 error - what is the actual error message, and do you have a JSON file that you can share that reproduces the problem? Add the stacktrace to the question together with the file, if possible.

Comment: Is there by any chance just an `@` missing in front of your file path? Is this the reason why you first said `400` and then `500` in the comment?

Comment: @Harald you are right, I missed it when asking the question. The Solr docs and curl man page specifies that `@` has to be used when uploading local file. I get `500` status code when prepending `@` to the file path. See updated question.

Comment: @MatsLindh added stacktrace and sample JSON file to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently Solr doesn't allow `null` as a field value (it causes Solr to throw `NullPointerException`). After changing `null` in my example JSON file to a String, I was able to upload the files following the steps described in the question.